# python tkinter применить значение в виджете при переключении между виджетами

Tags: python, tkinter, виджет

Как применить значение в виджете(tk.Entry) при нажатии кнопкой мыши в другом виджете либо в свободной части формы\ другой программы и т.д.?

Пример: в tk.Entry введено значение 5. При нажатии в другой tk.Entry, либо в любое место формы\рабочего стола и т.д. - выполнить команду. Тот же print. Но, выполнить единожды. Многократные выполнения не нужны.

Видел подобное в различных cad\cae программах, но, как реализовать, не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужно отлавливать события потери фокуса текстовым полем (`<FocusOut>`). Чтобы запоминать, что действие уже выполнялось, можно отмечать выполнение действия в глобальной переменной:

```
already_printed = False


def on_focus_out(event):
    global already_printed
    if not already_printed:
        print("Some action")
        already_printed = True


entry.bind("<FocusOut>", on_focus_out)
```